# Adding WHERE clause to query slows the query down - even though column is indexed

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

So the Users TABLE has 40 million rows.  The below query runs fast enough (less than 1 second) if I don't have a WHERE clause
 If I put the WHERE clause in the query, it takes about 10 minutes to return the result set.
 I added a index on the UserType column but it didn't seem to effect the response time for some reason

```
  CREATE INDEX idx_users_user_type ON Users (UserType);
```

The query:

```
SELECT  TOP 100
        *
FROM Users u
    INNER JOIN Company c ON c.ID = u.CompanyID
    INNER JOIN Location l ON l.ID = u.LocationId
WHERE
    u.UserType = 'manager'
```

There are only 3 values for UserType:

```
manager
employee
temp
```

I don't want to change the column to an INT value if possible because an ETL process imports data into this table that is hard to change now.

Comment: TOP without an ORDER BY?

Comment: `TOP` without `ORDER BY` makes little sense.

Comment: Why SELECT *? The index won't help much because SQL Server will still have to do look-ups on every record returned to get the values for all the other columns. Try selecting just what you need from Users, and INCLUDE those columns in your UserType index. If you look at your SQL Plan, you'll likely see exactly why things are so terrible.

Comment: Are the columns `u.CompanyID` and `u.LocationId` foreign keys? Are they nullable or not?

Answer (score 5):

First, you should read [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by/) on using `TOP` without an `ORDER BY`. The short version is you can't guarantee the results will be the same with each run, unless you have an `ORDER BY`.

The first query runs fast because SQL Server simply does a TABLE SCAN for the *first* 100 rows. Easy. Now you add a `WHERE` clause... SQL Server has to find all the rows where that predicate is true. Sure, you have an index, this can help. SQL Server will (or could) use that index but if it does, it will then have to do a Key Lookup to retrieve the rest of your columns (since you `SELECT *`). So, it's having to do A LOT more work. It's very likely that the index isn't even being used since SQL Server could decide it is faster to simply do a TABLE SCAN to check that predicate on every row, versus doing the key lookup. This of course means you have to read 40 million rows (check out how large your table is... this needs to come into memory. I bet it's paged to disk,maybe even [spilling to TEMPDB](https://www.brentozar.com/blitzcache/tempdb-spills/)).

So, of course it is going to be slower... you are checking a condition against 40 million rows instead of pulling a *random* `TOP 100`. If you want further help, [we need the execution plans at a minimum](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/03/getting-help-with-a-slow-query/), with all DDL (create table, create index) statements.

Other options to explore are:

- [Filtered Indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes?view=sql-server-2017)
- Query Hints, like [OPTIMIMZE FOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query?view=sql-server-2017)
- [Updating Statistics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/update-statistics-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [Index Maintenance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/reorganize-and-rebuild-indexes?view=sql-server-2017) ideally via [Ola Hallengren's Solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html). You'll probably want to read about [Index Fragmentation](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/08/sql-server-index-fragmentation/) first though, and the difference between internal and external and why it may or not matter :)
- [Changing your MAXDOP if it's at the default 0](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2806535/recommendations-and-guidelines-for-the-max-degree-of-parallelism-confi) thought his is getting beyond the initial scope of this question and opens up Pandora's box of other things you should be checking on your server.

Comment: Oh cool. That excellent article from Conor Cunningham is back!!! It was taken down awhile back and I had asked him to see if MS would reinstate that one as myself, and lots of others, reference that article a lot.

Comment: Yessir @SeanLange! I was referencing WayBackMachine before they finally brought it back, thankfully!

Answer (score 1):

You could add index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_users_user_type_company_id_location_id 
          ON Users (CompanyId, LocationId,UserType);
```